# How do I make <select> tag Microsoft Edge compatible?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge, compatibility, struts-1

I'm editing jsp files which uses struts1.

```
<html:select property="someProperty"
      style="width:110;height:110" styleClass="someClass">
```

However upon opening it in Microsoft Edge. The drop down already makes use of the fixed in line height which totally ruins the design.

To try resolving this minute problem, I have tried 2 ways.

**First Solution:**

- Created a javascript to remove the "style" attribute when class is "someClass"

The problem with this one is that many jsp files are calling this class. So a lot will be affected.

**Second Solution:**

-Delete style manually for all jsp files

This actually works but requires changing 50+ files.

I was wondering if there is any other workaround for this one?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have CSS related issue. I suggest you to remove style attribute and try to create a CSS class and add your CSS code for select drop down there. than you can use that CSS class for all select dropdowns.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Oh yes thanks. That's what I end up doing. I just thought that maybe there would be a global fix that wouldn't need editing all select dropdowns for jsp files.

Comment: Looks like you had solved your issue by creating a CSS class for select option drop downs. I suggest you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer may help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a shot at this answer because I don't know anything about struts but you don't have any units defined in your CSS. That is, you have `height:110` which is invalid. Set this to `height:110px`. Same with `width`.

The `px`, or other unit such as `em`, are required.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have CSS related issue. I suggest you to remove style attribute and try to create a CSS class and add your CSS code for select drop down there. than you can use that CSS class for all select dropdowns.